# PHP concatenate strings without whitespace

Tags: php, string, whitespace, addition

Let's say that

```
$result='first';
```

when I do:

```
$result.='second';
```

I got 'first second' instead of 'firstsecond'.
How to perfom concatenatation without adding this whitespace?

Edit:

That's the code. It should translate simple string to "pilots alphabet".

```
function converting($words){
  echo $words;
  global $result;
  $result='';
  for($x=0; $x<strlen($words); $x++){
    switch($words{$x}){
      case ' ':
        $result.=' ';
        break;
      case 'A':
        $result.='Alfa';
        break;
      case 'B':
        $result.='Bravo';
        break;
      case 'C':
        $result.='Charlie';
        break;
      case 'D':
        $result.='Delta';
        break;
      case 'E':
        $result.='Echo';
        break;
      case 'F':
        $result.='Foxtrot';
        break;
      case 'G':
        $result.='Golf';
        break;
      case 'H':
        $result.='Hotel';
        break;
      case 'I':
        $result.='India';
        break;
      case 'J':
        $result.='Juliett';
        break;
      case 'K':
        $result.='Kilo';
        break;
      case 'L':
        $result.='Lima';
        break;
      case 'M':
        $result.='Mike';
        break;
      case 'N':
        $result.='November';
        break;
      case 'O':
        $result.='Oscar';
        break;
      case 'P':
        $result.='Papa';
        break;
      case 'Q':
        $result.='Quebec';
        break;
      case 'R':
        $result.='Romeo';
        break;
      case 'S':
        $result.='Sierra';
        break;
      case 'T':
        $result.='Tango';
        break;
      case 'U':
        $result.='Uniform';
        break;
      case 'V':
        $result.='Victor';
        break;
      case 'W':
        $result.='Whiskey';
        break;
      case 'X':
        $result.='Xray';
        break;
      case 'Y':
        $result.='Yankee';
        break;
      case 'Z':
        $result.='Zulu';
        break;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

That switch also adds some cases that I have not defined. It is adding other characters to result, like '?' or '!' if they appear in 'words' string.

Comment: The `.=` operator does not add space. The space is already in one of your strings.

Comment: as above, but if you need to you could use `trim()` on the string before concatenation

Comment: Well I am sure it's not. I am doing .= inside switch - does it have something to do?

Comment: Please show code that replicates your issue.

Comment: _"Well I am sure it's not."_ I'll bet you a beer it is. :)

Comment: @Sheb unlikely you have found a bug no one else ever has.

Comment: @Sheb A straight string concat will not add white space. Can you show us the code for your switch statement?

Comment: @RToyota code added

Comment: @chris85 code added

Comment: It seems to work correctly: https://ideone.com/STKwb7

Comment: The only space in the output is from the space in the input string, which is because of `case ' ':`

Comment: BTW, the preferred syntax for accessing a string element is `$words[$x]`.

Comment: its the  "NATO phonetic alphabet" not "pilots alphabet", to be pedantic

Comment: In fact it seems that this code is ok! Well this is the "If you can read this..." challenge from Codewars and with their compilation I got bugs.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't identify your problem (other posters are correct, your code is essentially right, the problem must be in the souce string), you may want to consider this somewhat more simple solution:

```
<?php

function phoneticAlphabetTranslation($word) {
    $translations = [
        ' ' => ' ',
        'a' => 'Alpha',
        'b' => 'Beta',
        'c' => 'Charlie',
    ];

    return str_ireplace(array_keys($translations), array_values($translations), $word);
}

echo phoneticAlphabetTranslation('abAC');
```

each of the keys in `$translations` will be mapped to its value in the supplied string. Added benefit of being case-insensitive. If you don't desire case-insensitivity, just replace `str_ireplace` with `str_replace`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am learning php since 2 days so that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You may already have invisible whitespace in your strings.

Try passing the strings through trim before adding to the **$result** variable

```
$result = trim('first');
$result .= trim('second');
echo $result;
```

Alternatively remove all whitespace after joining.

```
echo str_replace(" ", "", $result)
```